# Arithmetic operations on Complex Numbers

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11, object

[Here is the error I am Facing In Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0eHw.jpg)I am trying to make a program that Takes two complex Numbers from User and then in Output it shows Addition, Subtraction and Multiplication Of these Numbers I have Provided mY code Below But It Does not Show Correct Output I have Tried very much But it's not working
a little Help would be appreciated

```
  #include<iostream>
  using namespace std;
  class complexnumber
  {
    int real, image;
    public:
    {
    real = real;
    image = image;
}
complexnumber operator +(complexnumber c2)
{
    complexnumber temp;
    temp.real = real + c2.real;
    temp.image = image + c2.image;
    return temp;
}
    complexnumber operator-(complexnumber c2)
    {
        complexnumber temp;
        temp.real = real - c2.real;
        temp.image = image - c2.image;
        return temp;
    }
    complexnumber operator*(complexnumber c2)
    {
        complexnumber temp;
        temp.real = real * c2.real + (image *c2.image)*(-1);
        temp.image = image * c2.real+c2.image*real;
        return temp;
    }
    void display(complexnumber c)
    {
        if (c.image < 0)
        {
            cout << real <<  image << "i";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << real << "+" << image << "i";
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    int real1, real2, image1, image2;
    cout << "enter real value 1:";
    cin >> real1;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "enter real value 2:";
    cin >> real2;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "enter imaginary value 1:";
    cin >> image1;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "enter imaginary value 2:";
    cin >> image2;
    cout << endl;
    complexnumber c1, c2, c3, c4, c5;
    c1.set(real1, image1);
    c2.set(real2, image2);
    c3 = c1 + c2;
    c4 = c1 - c2;
    c5=c1*c2;
    cout << "addition of two complex number       ";
    c3.display(c3);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "subtraction of two complex number    ";
    c4.display(c4);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "multiplication of two complex number ";
    c5.display(c5);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on `It Does not Show Correct Output`.

Comment: BTW, I think you wanna implement each one of those binary operators (an operator which takes two operands) as global functions (`friend` of your class if needed) rather than as member functions.

Comment: This doesn't compile

Comment: Also, your implementation of member function `display` implies that you kinda fail to comprehend one of the basic ideas behind classes and member functions (then you end up writing things like `c3.display(c3)`, `c4.display(c4)`, etc).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This code can't be compiled but you linked an image of runtime output. This means you didn't provide your actual code.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the standard complex number class?

Answer (score 0):

```
public:
{
real = real;
image = image;
}
```

I'm assuming this is your `set` function that you are invoking in main

```
public:
void set(int real, int image){

real = real;
image = image;

}
```

Here this is not setting the member variables `real` and `image` to the parameter values from fucntion`set`. This is just assigning the passed variable back to itself. The compiler will first look for a local variable or constructor argument called "real", and only if it doesn't find one will it start looking for a class member called "real" . The result is that the above statment "real=real" will assign the value stored in argument "real" to argument "real" rendering it a useless statement.

```
public:
void set(int real, int image){
this->real = real;
this->image = image;
}
```

This will get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This code helps.**:)**

> ```
> int real, image;
> public:
> void set(int real, int image)
> {
> this->real = real;
> this->image = image;
> }
>
> complexnumber operator +(complexnumber c2)
> {
>     complexnumber temp;
>     temp.real = real + c2.real;
>     temp.image = image + c2.image;
>     return temp;
> }
> complexnumber operator-(complexnumber c2)
> {
>     complexnumber temp;
>     temp.real = real - c2.real;
>     temp.image = image - c2.image;
>     return temp;
> }
> complexnumber operator*(complexnumber c2)
> {
>     complexnumber temp; 
>     temp.real = real * c2.real + (image *c2.image)*(-1);
>     temp.image = image * c2.real+c2.image*real;
>     return temp;
> }
> void display()
> {
>     if (this->image < 0)
>     {
>         cout << this->real <<  this->image << "i";
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         cout << this->real << "+" << this->image << "i";
>     }
> } }; int main() {
> int real1, real2, image1, image2;
> cout << "enter real value 1:";
> cin >> real1;
> cout << endl;
> cout << "enter real value 2:";
> cin >> real2;
> cout << endl;
> cout << "enter imaginary value 1:";
> cin >> image1;
> cout << endl;
> cout << "enter imaginary value 2:";
> cin >> image2;
> cout << endl;
> complexnumber c1, c2, c3, c4, c5;
> c1.set(real1, image1);
> c2.set(real2, image2);
> c3 = c1 + c2;//(1+3i)+(2+4i)
> c4 = c1 - c2;//(1+3i)-(2+4i)
> c5= c1 * c2; //(1+3i)(2+4i) = (1)(2)+(1)(4i)+(3i)(2)+(3i)(4i) 
>             //              = (2) +(4i)+(6i)(12i^2)
>             //              = 2+10i+12i^2
>             //(i^2 == -1)   = 2 + 10i-12 = -10+10i
> cout << "addition of two complex number       ";
> c3.display();//Dont need to pass object. Its already has c3 object
> cout << endl;
> cout << "subtraction of two complex number    ";
> c4.display();
> cout << endl;
> cout << "multiplication of two complex number ";
> c5.display();
> cout << endl;
> return 0; }
> ```

Let me know for any clarifications.**:)**